# Django DetailView with a form

Tags: python, django-forms

I am working on a Todo list and was wondering the best way to add a form to a DetailView.  I am now assuming from reading around that I need to make a function to do it but was curious if I could use a CBV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  `FormView` for this task.

Please look up the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) for usages.

I used this CBV a lot in my project and found it greatly separate the logics.